# RegEx pattern to match over a single line or more

Tags: c#, regex

I'm parsing a log file to identify and retrieve information about failures. Regular Expressions seem to be the right way to go about this.

Here's my initial pattern: `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}.*`

This works for well for single lines like this:

```
2011-02-06 02:17:54.9886|FATAL|ClassName|Failure data|StackLine:0:0
```

This doesn't work for information that spans multiple lines.

```
2011-02-06 02:19:04.4087|FATAL|ClassName|Message  
Failure data  
Additional message |StackLine:0:0
```

Here is what a couple of lines in the log look like:

```
2011-02-06 02:17:54.9886|FATAL|ClassName|Failure data|5th StackLine:0:0
4th StackLine:0:0  
3rd StackLine:0:0  
2nd StackLine:0:0  
1st StackLine:0:0 

 2011-02-06 02:19:04.4087|FATAL|ClassName|Message  
Failure data  
Additional message |7th StackLine:0:0  
6th StackLine:0:0  
5th StackLine:0:0  
4th StackLine:0:0  
3rd StackLine:0:0  
2nd StackLine:0:0  
1st StackLine:0:0
```

The phrase "StackLine" represents a method signature in the dumped call stack. For example, here two different "StackLine" examples:

```
ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup at offset 0 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0
```

and

```
OnXmlMsgReceived at offset 128 in file:line:column d:\buildserver\source\svnroot\DepotManager\trunk\src\DepotManager.Core\Gating\AutoGate\Wherenet\Zla\EventSink.cs:115:17
```

In an ideal world, I would just get the line, starting at the time stamp through that first line:character notation (which is frequently 0:0).

How would I go about creating a pattern that would match both?

Comment: You have to specify the language you are using the regex from. For "complex" regexes it's very important.

Comment: do you always have a blank line between "logs"?

Comment: @xanatos - I'm not targeting any language at the moment. But let's call it C# and I'll tag the post with it.

Comment: @xanatos - Yes, there is always a space between the blocks in the log file.

Comment: May I suggest naming your captures? (?<line>.*?(?<StaackLine>StaackLine:(?<param1>\d+):(?<param2>\d+))\r\n)) Look at the Match object to see the resulting tree-structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match a line starting with a date and all lines following it that do not start with a date.

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}.*$(?:\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*)*
```

Here is a Rubular example:
http://www.rubular.com/r/1BIoLZ5tfs

**edit 2**: If you want to stop at the first `:0:0` you can use the following regex as long as you have a multi-line option enabled so that the `.` character will also match newlines:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:.*?:\d+:\d+
```

And here is a new Rubular: http://www.rubular.com/r/rfR1wqDHR8

Comment: In the second case, which is what's tripping me up, the pattern you list matches the first three lines (which I want) and the remaining stack lines too (which I don't want).

Comment: I want to stop at the first 0:0. "StackLine" is a place holder for a call signature in the call stack.

Comment: The edit 2 is the closest yet, though it chokes on embedded time stamp. This minor tweak seems to do the trick though. `^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:.*?:\d+:\d+\r\n`

Answer (score 1):

```
var log = @"2011-02-06 02:17:54.9886|FATAL|ClassName|Failure data|StackLine:0:0
2011-02-06 02:19:04.4087|FATAL|ClassName|Message
Failure data
Additional message |7th StackLine:0:0
6th StaackLine:0:0
5th StaackLine:0:0
4th StaackLine:0:0
3rd StaackLine:0:0
2nd StaackLine:0:0
1st StaackLine:0:0
2011-02-06 02:17:54.9886|FATAL|ClassName|Failure data|5th StackLine:0:0 4th StackLine:0:0
3rd StackLine:0:0
2nd StackLine:0:0
1st StackLine:0:0
2011-02-06 02:19:04.4087|FATAL|ClassName|Message
Failure data
Additional message |7th StackLine:0:0
6th StaackLine:0:0
5th StaackLine:0:0
4th StaackLine:0:0
3rd StaackLine:0:0
2nd StaackLine:0:0
1st StaackLine:0:0";
var regex = @"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}.*?";
var matches = Regex.Matches(log, regex);
var count = matches.Count; // count = 4
```

Comment: No, this doesn't do what I need it to. I get four matches with the following values:2011-02-06 02, 2011-02-06 02, 2011-02-06 02, and 2011-02-06 02. This is copying and pasting the code into project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression that matches all your lines:
`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}[\S\s]*`

The reasen your regex didn't work is, because the dot-modifier rarely functions as an "match everything"

Comment: This gets me closer, but now it will match more than just the line. It would match both chunks, beyond what I want.

Comment: Didn't have suitable test data then :) Here this works with your example: `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[\S\s]*?:\d+:\d+`- @amber

Answer (score 0):

PCRE has [modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) and you need `PCRE_DOTALL`. You didn't specify a language so I can't give you more than a PHP example: `preg_match('/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}.*/s'`

Comment: I'm going to be using this in a C# app, but I'm doing the raw creation of the pattern in [RegEx Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/). Adding the /s to the end of the pattern caused no matches in the testing UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}[\s\S]*?$^\s*$", 
                   RegexOptions.Multiline);

var matches = rx.Matches(yourText);
```

Be aware that with `\d` you could catch non european digits, but considering that your file is quite "fixed" in format, you shouldn't have any problem (`\d` catches all of these: 
[Unicode Characters in the 'Number, Decimal Digit' Category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm))

This will work only if there is a blank line at the end of each "log". Even the last log must have a blank line, so the format must be

```
2011-02-06 02:17:54.9886|FATAL|ClassName|Failure data|StackLine
secondary line of the previous line
(blank)
2011-02-06 02:17:56.9886|FATAL|ClassName|Failure data|StackLine
(blank)
```